# Is it possible to add Excel sheets using alasql in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, alasql

I want to export data of two different arrays in a single excel document.
The data of **two different arrays** should be exported in **two different sheets**.

```
$scope.details= {
              "boys": [
                       {"name":"Jeet", "age":25},
                       {"name":"John", "age":24}
                      ],
              "girls":[
                       {"name":"Gita", "age":25},
                       {"name":"Sima", "age":24}
                      ]
               }
```

Now if I write

```
alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSX("Details.xlsx",{headers:true}) FROM ?',[$scope.details.boys]);
```

It will export the details of boys only in the excel sheet.
**How do I export for both boys and girls in a single excel document in two different sheets?** Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create two different sheets with two different arrays holding boys and girls information and then export like below

```js
$scope.details= {
              "boys": [
                       {"name":"Jeet", "age":25},
                       {"name":"John", "age":24}
                      ],
              "girls":[
                       {"name":"Gita", "age":25},
                       {"name":"Sima", "age":24}
                      ]
               }
var boys = $scope.details.boys;
var girls = $scope.details.girls;
var opts = [{ sheetid: 'Boys', headers: true }, { sheetid: 'Girls', headers: true }];
alasql('SELECT INTO XLSX("Details.xlsx",?) FROM ?', [opts, [boys, girls]]);
```